# What's the source of "2.303" in Van't Hoff equation?

Tags: thermodynamics

I've seen a "2.303" term multiplied to $R$ in Van't Hoff equation several times.

Here is one example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_equation#Error_propagation

> $$\Delta H^\circ=2.303R\frac{\log K_1-\log K_2}{\frac1{T_2}-\frac1{T_1}}$$

What is this number and where does it come from?

Comment: Related: [Help me understand the correlation between the equilibrium constant and delta G](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/26954/7951)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the multiplier used when converting the equation to use a base 10 log instead of a natural log.

It comes out to be the natural log of 10.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Burak's answer, which states that 2.303 is the multiplier, the correct converison is:

$$\ln(x) = 2.303\cdot\log_{10}(x)$$

Or as a divisor to convert the natural logarithm to a base 10 log:
$$\log_{10}(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{2.303}$$

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. For more information in general have a look at the [help]. I have reformatted and reworded your answer in order to reflect the current situation. Please have a look and edit as needed.